# Pandas: Find Number of Rows within window of Timestamp (before & after) for every row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to efficiently count the number of rows within a timestamp window on both sides of each row. For example, if I have a dataframe sorted by the `timestamp` column

```
timestamp         
2018-09-19 00:53:48
2018-09-19 00:53:49
2018-09-19 00:53:53
2018-09-19 00:53:54
2018-09-19 00:53:55
2018-09-19 00:53:60
```

and I want to find the number of rows before and after each row that is within 3 seconds, I should get something like this:

```
timestamp                 before      after
2018-09-19 00:53:48       0           1
2018-09-19 00:53:49       1           0
2018-09-19 00:53:53       0           2
2018-09-19 00:53:54       1           2
2018-09-19 00:53:55       2           1
2018-09-19 00:53:57       2           0
```

An obvious way to go about this is to iterate through the rows, perform `.loc` twice to select sub-dataframes  (one for the leading window, one for the trailing window), and then just count the size of those dataframes. However, that does not strike me as very efficient, so I'm wondering how much this could be sped up?

Comment: is it guaranteed that the timestamp is sorted?

Comment: yes, it is guaranteed the timestamp is sorted. However, not every timestamp is guaranteed to be unique - there will be duplicates

Comment: I am afraid I don't see a soluton without iteration to get the next n rows for each row